# Problems with using github project BookBuilder

Tags: python, windows, github, crash, manjaro

I found this great project on github called book builder (https://github.com/raccrompton/BookBuilder) however Ive been struggling to get it working. On github there are two options how to use it and a video tutorial, but it seems outdated.

What Ive tried:
First I tried following the first option (if you dont want to touch any code option).
I booted windows and downloaded the app, changed the setting, it loaded the setting, loaded the engine, started working. And then after a few seconds the window that is running just disappears.
The Bookbuilder.exe application that I ran is deleted, the engine (in this case its called stockfishwin15.exe) is also deleted and in the folder Bookbuilderwin only the config.yaml is left + maybe the BookA and BookB, which were there upon download.

Then I tried the second option, first thing I noticed was that there was no config. I already had visual studio installed and python as well, on manjaro I ran succesfully the command pip3 install -r requirements.txt. Then I had to add the engine but I realised that I cant as the config file does not exist, so I copied it from the folder with the windows app, tried setting it up downloading stockfish for linux, when I run it nothing happens, it completes with no output.

I also tried the second option on windows, but pip install doesnt work there and I would much rather run this on manjaro as it is hella faster.

[This is the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4kui.png)

My configured config.yaml (I didnt really know what to set the last values to, but I figured that what was there should be fine.):

```
#BOOK SETTINGS
OPENINGBOOK: [{"Name": "Queens pawn", "pgn": "1. d4"}]
#add the starting point PGNs you want to create repertoires for, with starting point pgns.
#The format for multiple PGNs and chapters looks like this: [{"Name": "YourBlackOpeningName, "pgn": "1. e4 e5"},{"Name": "YourWhiteOpeningName2", "pgn": "1. e4 e5 2. f4"}]
LONGTOSHORT: 1
#if you want the chapter ordered from long lines to short lines, instead of short to long, change to "1". Else 0.


#DATABASE SETTINGS
VARIANT: 'standard' 
#Variants to include in the analysis
SPEEDS: ['rapid']
#comma separated Formats to include in the analysis ['blitz,rapid,classical,correspondence'] 
RATINGS: ['1600,1800,2000,2200']
#Ratings of the players to include in the analysis ['1600,1800,2000,2200,2500'] 
MOVES: 10
#The number of most played moves to search over for the best move (minimum 5)

#MOVE SELECTION SETTINGS
DEPTHLIKELIHOOD: 0.001
#IF YOU WANT MORE / DEEPER LINES, DECREASE THIS NUMBER. 0.01 = responses for moves played every 1 in 100 games, 0.001 every 1 in 1000 etc.
#this controls how deep moves and lines are generated. The smaller the number the deeper the lines. Once cumulative line likelihood reaches this probability threshold, no futher continuations will be added (in percentage so 0.0025 = 0.25%)
ALPHA: 0.0001
#The larger this number the more likely we are to select moves with less data. This is the confidence interval alpha (EG 0.05 = 95% CI), for deciding the lower bounds of how good a move's winrate is.
MINPLAYRATE: 0.001
#minimum probability of our move being played in a position to be considered as a 'best move' candidate, as a percentage (0.05= 5%)
MINGAMES: 10 
#games where our moves were played this or less than this will be discarded (unless top engine move) (25 = 25 games).
CONTINUATIONGAMES: 10 
# games where moves played this or less than this will not be considered a valid opponent continuation (ie we don't want to be inferring cumulative probability or likely lines from tiny amounts of games/1 game)
DRAWSAREHALF: 1
#if you want to count draws as half a win (0.5 points), for the win rate calculation, select 1. Else 0. With 0 draws will count as as losses for the win rate calculation.


#ENGINE SETTINGS
ENGINEPATH: 'C:\home\admin_\Desktop\BookBuilder-main\stockfish_15.1_linux_x64'
#the filepath where the engine is stored on your computer, so it can be accessed.
#It should be wrapped in quotes (eg 'path/path'), and end in the actual engine file (not the folder), so 'C:\Folder\Chess\BookBuilder-main\stockfish15.exe' on Windows or '/Users/User/Downloads/BookBuilder-main/stockfish' on Mac, for example
#Some users reported errors if the engine has _ in the file name.
CAREABOUTENGINE: 1
#care about engine eval of position or engine finishing = 1, dont care = 0. If this is 0 then no engine functionality will work.
ENGINEDEPTH: 25
#RECOMMENDED minimum 20+ ideally 30+ for stable evaluations in the opening phase.
#what depth the engine should evaluate best moves. the higher the depth the longer the evaluation will take.
ENGINEFINISH: 1
#if we want the engine to complete lines upto the cumulative likelihood, where where data from our perspective doesn't meet minimum criteria. For this kind of finishing, 1. Otherwise 0, and lines will end where there's no good human data for one player.
SOUNDNESSLIMIT: -99
#recommended not closer to 0 than -50 for White, or - 80 for Black repertoires. Engine evaluations swing a lot in the opening.
#maximum centipawns we are willing to be down in engine eval, provided the winrate is better (-300 = losing by 3 pawns in eval). We never give up a forced mate, however.
MOVELOSSLIMIT: -99
#recommended not closer to 0 than -50. Engine evaluations swing a lot in the opening.
#maximum eval centipawns we are willing to lose vs engine's best move to play a higher winrate move. We never give up a forced mate, however.
IGNORELOSSLIMIT: 299
#centipawns advantage above which we won't care if we play a move that hits our loss limit, if it has a higher win rate (is easier to win)
ENGINETHREADS: 1
#Increase this number to speed the engine up. It's how many threads you want the engine to use (check your comp and set 1 if unsure)
#for reference my safemax is 20
ENGINEHASH: 3072
#Increase this number to speed the engine up. It's how much hash (RAM) you want the engine to use (check your comp and set to 16 if unsure)
#for reference my safe max is 12288

# Change this to true/false depending if you want to see detailed output in your terminal when running the program
PRINT_INFO_TO_CONSOLE: true
```